# Boghe IMS client automation

Tags: python-2.7, sip, ims

I was trying to automate `Boghe IMS` client on `python 2.7.9`, Can anyone help me how to find the co-ordinates of `Boghe GUI` and also how to pass "string" over that co-ordinates.

UserA(Boghe GUI) to UserB(Boghe GUI) IMS call has established manually.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the standard AutoIt Version (without python), you get a programm called "AutoIt v3 Window Info". Take the Finder Tool and hover it over your window and there you go.

Also there is the command [WinGetPos](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetPos.htm). Just give the windowname and read the data from the array. More info in the linked website.

I dont know Boghe IMS, if there is a textbox you can focuse on it and use the [Send](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) command.

```
Send("UserA(Boghe GUI) to UserB(Boghe GUI) IMS call has established manually.")
```

Comment: Thanks for info.

We are using standard AutoIt v3 version. Here i am trying to automate Boghe IMS client GUI and here my point is how to find AutoIt positions if GUI position get changes everytime.

Thanks in advance!!

Regards,
Sainath

Comment: What does everytime mean? If it is on startup you can WinWait() for the window and then get the info with WinGetPos. If you mean that the user is moving it you can do a WhileLoop and check the position and do your action when it changes.